# Avoid stretching of grid column when column's content width changes

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a problem with columns in grid. I would like to have columns with the same width and this width should not depend on the content of the columns.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid Margin="5" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <telerik:RadTreeView Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.Column="0" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding TreeView0}" />
    <telerik:RadTreeView Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.Column="1" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding TreeView1}" />
    <telerik:RadTreeView Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.Column="2" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding TreeView2}" />
    <telerik:RadTreeView Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.Column="3" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding TreeView3}" />
</Grid>
```

When I am expanding tree in RadTreeView the column changes it's width and other columns changes respectively. But I would like to have four columns with width = 1/4 of grid's width. RadTreeView has its own ScrollBar for horizontal scrolling.

---

### **Solution**

I have resolved my problem with help of *talegna*. I have defined *MaxWidth* property for every RadTreeView control:

```
MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=Column, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource TreeWidthConverter}}"
```

I am using converter for just substract the width of margins.

Comment: That *is* how to define four columns of equal `Width`. Maybe there is a property on the `RadTreeView` that stops it from growing horizontally? I'd ask Telerik if I were you.

Comment: I don't remember there being an allow scroll function on the treeview but have you considered using css to limit the width of the treeview and force it to scroll?

Comment: It is in WPF actually. I have made it working now using your advice to limit the treeview and force it to scroll. I will probably write answer to my questions for those who will have the same problem in the future and will look for it on Stackoverflow.